# Constrain two items to top and bottom inside linear layout

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have a constraint layout and inside an image and a linear layout. The linear layout contains two text views which I would like to appear on top and bottom of the linear layout constrains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatStatusTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However the second text view appears indeed underneath the first one, but not constrained to the bottom of the linear layout:

[image]

How can I constrain the bottom text to the bottom of the linear layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case where a `RelativeLayout` is more suitable.
All you have to do is set the attributes `android:layout_alignParentTop` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` to `true` for the 2 views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/chatLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatStatusTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need to use RelativeLayout or any other ViewGroup in this case. Based on [Performance and view hierarchies](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) page, it's better to remove RelativeLayout in this case.

Comment: @MirMiladHosseiny *it's better to remove RelativeLayout in this case* is this your solution? If you have one then post it.

Comment: Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59805091/1162154).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a nested LinearLayout, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chatPictureIV"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/chatNameTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatStatusTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Top"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chatStatusTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:text="Bottom"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any nested ViewGroup. Based on [Performance and view hierarchies](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies) it's better to handle it by root ConstraintLayout in a flat hierarchi.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/chatLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/chat_image_size"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatNameTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Top"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chatPictureIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/chatPictureIV" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatStatusTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottom"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/chatPictureIV"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/chatPictureIV" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```